# Why is James Bond saying "We didn't get yet"?

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past

I've recently seen the trailer for the new James Bond movie and he is saying: "We all have our secrets. We just didn't get to yours yet".

Shouldn't have he said "we just haven't got to them yet"? Also considering he is British.

Comment: In your interpretation, Bond wants to get to *our secrets*. But it is *yours* that he will be getting you.

Comment: Yes, as a British English speaker I would have expected him to say that too. Presumably the scriptwriters were influenced by American usage.

Comment: Please correct your question title, as it refers to a different phrase than the question body.

Comment: I definitely feel "we just haven't got to them yet" would be better (or more correct). "yet" implies relative to the present, which means you'd use the perfect. (At least, if "yet" is part of the sentence - colloquially you can use "yet" as a threat for the future, and say "We didn't get to them. Yet.") But there is a lot of confusion between "did" and "have", between present perfect and past tense. So it's not surprising to see a mistake. Is this something Americans do differently?

Comment: "We haven't got to your secrets in our discussion" suggests the discussion is still going on.  "We didn't get to your secrets in our discussion" suggests the discussion has finished.  In the actual quote, the discussion is not mentioned, so it is difficult to say either is clearly wrong.

Comment: @StuartF - Yes, it's my understanding that an American would say "Did you have lunch yet?" where I would say "Have you had lunch yet?"

Answer (score 1):

James Bond is an expert in killing techniques, parachutes, guns, knives, swords, missiles, explosives, fast cars, fast planes, fast motorbikes, helicopters, autogyros, rockets,  unarmed combat, armed combat, poker, baccarat,  martinis, wine vintages, parkour.

Grammar is not on the list.

Comment: What's actually wrong with the original wording?  Even assuming the original is grammatically incorrect, the OP's suggested alternative doesn't mean the same thing.